# Tandem breaker compatible?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Based on this panel photo, is it tandem breaker compatible? I see CHT noted but don't know how to decipher the matrix. I have already done a load calc to make sure I have enough overhead.

[image: Panel Cover]

---Edit---
Full panel picture added as requested. 200a main service.

[image: Full panel]

Comment: The answer is almost definitely **Yes**, as all but one of the listed combinations allows for CHT breakers. However, it would be very helpful to see (a) the actual panel showing all the existing breakers, including the main breaker, and (b) the rest of the label, including the diagram - there are *some* panels where only some of the breaker spaces are allowed to have tandems.

Comment: Assuming the circled config is correct, you've cleared one hurdle. Looks like the panel only has 32 spaces so you've probably cleared the second hurdle. Take a picture and we can give you the 100% clear.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact photo added

Comment: @KMJ photo added

Comment: Is this in the USA?  It seems odd to have the refrigerator share a breaker handle with kitchen countertop outlets.  Being on a separate breaker is great, and required by electrical code in most places in the USA.  I ask where this is because the purpose of having the refrigerator on a separate breaker is so if something else trips a circuit breaker then food doesn't spoil in the refrigerator.  By putting the refrigerator on a shared breaker handle that defeats the purpose.  This is likely a code violation in the USA.  It's not related to your question but I thought it should be pointed out.

Comment: @MacGuffin Realistically, how often do you have kitchen receptacle **overcurrent trips** unattended? Most overcurrent trips, in a reasonably modern house, are due to either a faulty appliance in use (motor burnout or whatever) or due to user overload (toaster and coffee pot on the same circuit at the same time). GFCI is a whole different story (because a little water from a leak can pop a GFCI), but these are standard breakers so GFCI on a receptacle on 1/2 an MWBC will have no effect on a refrigerator on the other 1/2.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  I agree with you that in practice it is unlikely for an over-current trip to happen while nobody is present to immediately clear the overload and reset the breaker but the intent of the rule is to keep power to the refrigerator even in case of an over current condition elsewhere.  Given that this appears to be a fairly recent install I suspect that it meets the code as written but fails to meet what the code intended.  If I had any say then I'd want it fixed.  Given that it may have been this way for years there's likely not much that can be done now.

Comment: Original build and inspection was in '96. From looking inside the panel the refrigerator circuit orientation seem original.

Comment: @MacGuffin The only way to "fix" this is a new circuit. If the kitchen is near the panel (mine is), great. If it is on the other side of the house and a different floor, not so easy. Also, "most places in the USA" implies "in the NEC". Can you provide a citation for that? I am interested in seeing exactly what code says, as that could give some hint (but not necessarily a guarantee) as to the intent. In my past experience (but I have not seriously researched it) most references to "refrigerator on its own circuit" have been as a way to avoid a GFCI requirement, which is becoming less practical

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact As far as I know having the refrigerator on a dedicated circuit is not in the NEC, but local building codes often require it.  Not every jurisdiction adopts NEC, there's other standards that are used as a starting point.  The NEC allows the refrigerator to share a circuit with other appliances but the list of appliances that don't allow a shared circuit often leaves electricians putting the refrigerator on its own circuit just to avoid any inspector questions later.  I realize a fix may not be easy but if someone is running new circuits then I suggest trying.

Comment: @MacGuffin What rule? Cite something specific.

Comment: Here's an example:  https://library.municode.com/ia/cedar_rapids/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=CH34ELCO  Section 34.42.  Local codes vary, and in my area codes like I cite appear to be the norm.

Comment: @MacGuffin I think you're reading something into this that isn't there. 34.42 does **NOT** say "thou shalt have a refrigerator circuit". What it *does* say is: *Other circuits, if installed, shall be as follows: * + *One separate 20-ampere circuit for a refrigerator. * - Meaning: If you want to have a separate refrigerator circuit, it should be a 20A circuit (implying, not a 15A circuit). And this in the section regarding computing loads - and it doesn't even include a lot of the usual stuff - e.g., bathroom circuits. In any case, without additional information I don't believe it actually

Comment: **requires** a dedicated refrigerator circuit.

Comment: @MacGuffin And actually back to the original issue: Refrigerator on MWBC. There are two very different reasons to say "refrigerator on its own circuit". One is "so there is no risk of an overload on that circuit" - i.e., to prevent frequent nuisance trips, marginally overloaded wire that doesn't actually trip a breaker, etc. For all of that, 1/2 of an MWBC is perfectly adequate. The other is "so an overload of *something else* doesn't cause the refrigerator to lose power" - for that an MWBC (with common trip, as is commonly done in modern times with a double breaker) would *not* be

Comment: appropriate. Even if you interpret the Cedar Rapids example to mean "if you have a refrigerator permanently installed then it should be on its own circuit", there is no real reason to expect that an MWBC would be a problem for that. In nearly all cases an MWBC is just as good as two separate circuits - it just complicates GFCI and AFCI protection.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Argue if you like but the way the code is read around here that would not be allowed.  My cite is not the complete code, it is not how every code is written, and I can see how that what is shown in the photo above likely met building code at the time.  Call it "bad form" as opposed to a "violation" if you prefer then.  I don't like it and if I could find an easy fix then I'd take it.

Comment: @MacGuffin I'll just say one more time: We can argue over the ambiguity of whether this code (but not the NEC - this is clearly a local amendment) **requires** a refrigerator circuit or not. But even if it does, it does not in any way indicate that an MWBC would not be perfectly adequate.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  I didn't claim this was a violation of the NEC, it could be a violation of local building code.  Code changes over time, usually to be more strict than be more lax.  I thought to point it out because it could come up in a future inspection, if there's significant enough renovation that it might need fixing or a variation on the rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You circled the wrong row, but that's OK. Your relevant main breaker row is # 3 - "CSR 25,000" - which matches your "CSR 25k" breaker. So you are OK with CHT breakers in this panel. I also found a spec. sheet that specifically references the NEC removing the circuit limit on panels - the implication is that the reason these were limited (or perhaps not available at all) previously was circuit limits, and without those limits you should be able to use them anywhere in a compatible panel.

You panel is **FULL**. You knew that. But it is worse than it might be on some panels. The problem is that CHT breakers are only available as 15/15, 20/20 and 15/20 pairs. Some other panels have larger tandems available. I don't know whether the reason Eaton doesn't offer larger tandems is due to technical limitations based on the 3/4" size (most other panels are 1") or if it is a marketing decision. But you have to live with it.

That means you can only turn the breakers into tandems that are 15A or 20A. That definitely includes your single 15A and 20A breakers - spaces, and you have 6 of those.

However, to make use of spaces with double-breakers you need at a minimum common shutoff and possibly common trip, depending on the type of circuit. For example, spaces 17 and 19 are a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit. That requires common shutoff. If I counted correctly, you have 7 MWBCs. The advantage of an MWBC is that it saves wire. But you may be paying for it now because you can't change those to tandems *unless* you can put them on the inner or outer pair of a quad - two tandems side-by-side. Eaton doesn't offer a CH quad. They do have them in the BR line, but that doesn't help. The workaround on *some* panel types is a handle tie. However, I don't see any handle ties for the CHT breakers, only for the full size CH breakers. None of this affects making use of the 6 single breaker spaces for tandems, but unless Eaton comes out with quads (and certifies them for use with existing panels) or handle ties, that's your absolute limit on this panel.

Comment: I appreciate it. I dont expect to add much load to the panel, just needed to add a couple new circuits and avoid tying into existing junctions.

Comment: Houston, we have a problem: there appear to be a lot of MWBCs in this panel. Those can't be used with normal tandems because they will be on the same phase and could double-load the neutral.

Comment: @KMJ Wrote it up already. Basically MWBC can only be done with tandems if you have an official quad (with common trip or at least common shutoff) - not available, or if you have handle ties to tie the inner pair of two tandems together - also not available. So limited here to just the 6 existing single breakers for conversion to tandems and then it is new panel or subpanel time.

Comment: No! You absolutely can't because code requires (it has not *always* required this, but for many years now) that MWBCs have common shutoff, and that appears to be unavailable for CHT.

Comment: I wrote it up as well, we said nearly the same thing. I couldn't find CHT ties either, and one of those single-pole locations is a GFCI so it's off the list. Plus there's the GFCI and AFCI requirements in 2017+ and particularly 2020+ code that might make this a real headache.

Comment: Thanks. I think there are plenty of non-MWBC breakers in there to support my needs.

Comment: @Brian just make sure you can meet the AFCI/GFCI requirements. See my answer for a few approaches you can use here. This is doable, just tricky.

Answer (score 5):

I see a lot of tied handles in this panel on what are nominally 120V circuits. That's a strong sign that these are actually Multi-Wire Branch Circuits or MWBCs. This is going to be a challenge, because the interaction between a MWBC and a tandem breaker is tricky.

In short: there's a few rules you need to follow with a MWBC. One of them is to tie the handles, so that if one is off, both are off. Another is to make sure that each hot leg of the MWBC is on a different phase. Tying the handles is not possible on CHT breakers, as Eaton doesn't make a tie accessory for the CHT breaker (or at least not one I'm aware of). And splitting the loads across phases can't be done easily even if you can tie the handles, since a CHT breaker ties down to a single phase and feeds both wires from it.

If you want to use tandems to gain circuits in this panel, I see precisely five single breaker locations that can be swapped out to tandems. Without more significant changes, at that point, you're full. Done. No more circuits in this panel as is.

That might not get you what you need, though, because CHT breakers are only made in thermal magnetic. They don't make GFCI or AFCI tandems in CH. If your area is on the 2017 code, it's going to be tricky to add circuits for many locations as you'll likely need to use inline AFCI or GFCI devices to do a compliant install. If it's a 2020 code area, it's going to be even more of a headache since most locations now require one or the other. Adding inline AFCIs and GFCIs works, it's just extra complexity to troubleshoot and deal with in the future.

There might be one way around it: moving the wire for the old circuits to tandems. If your inspector (AHJ) doesn't mind you replacing the breaker on an existing circuit with the old style, you can consolidate four of those five candidate single-pole circuits down to two new tandems by pairing them up. Now you have precisely two spaces to work with however you want. That might get you just what you need, even with AFCI and GFCI rules in place.

If any of these rules are making things tight, you're probably going to need to take a totally different approach: either a new panel, or a new subpanel. A subpanel is usually the easiest/cheapest way to go. You could move one of the 240V circuits to the subpanel, then hook it back to the main in the new freed-up location, and now you'll have plenty of space for whatever new circuits you need.